# Rounding float number in certain pattern in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to round a floating number in certain pattern. I want it to be only these floats:

**-1 , -0.5 , 0 , 0.5 , 1**

How can I do it in C#?

*(It is my first question here, so sorry if I have mistake)*

Comment: It's unclear what the mapping is here. 1.0 maps/rounds to... 1? I don't know. But then what does 2.0 map/round to? And 1e6? You've specified the range (-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), but what's the domain of input and what's the mapping?

Comment: I'm clamping it to between -1 and 1 , and for example if its 0.6, I need it to be 0.5

Comment: Ah, it'd be great if you could [edit] your question with that detail.

Comment: What would 0.75 be rounded to? 0.5 or 1?

Comment: Like a general math: 1

Comment: How about -0.75?

Comment: -0.75 would be -1.  I know I can make it with couple of if statements but I'm looking for more flexible and readable way

Comment: Yeah, it also works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is your input:

```
Mathf.round(x*2)/((float)2)
```